# Data of nested API calls is not rendering in component in react

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, axios

I am using react with flux and axios for API calls, I have implemented the nested API calls, I am getting data correctly from API and it shows me correctly in console, but issue is nested API call data is not rendering in component, here is my code

```
loadCategoryProducts(action) {

    axios.post(API, {
         "query": 'query {ProductListQuery(category :"'+action.params.category+'", subcategory :"'+action.params.subcategory+'"){productinfo{partterminologyid,aliasname,partterminologyname,usedescription,categoryname,subcategoryname}worldpacinfo{worldpaccategoryid,basevehicleidnumber,parttypeidnumber,branddescription,detaileddescription,Note,popularity,price,productimageurl,productpartnumber,productthumburl,ThumbURL,available,Part}}}',
    }).then(resp => {
        if(resp.data.data){
            var productsArr = resp.data.data['ProductListQuery'];
            var count = productsArr.length;
            productsArr.map(function(value, index) {
                if(value.worldpacinfo.basevehicleidnumber!='undefined') {
                    axios.post(API, {
                        "query": 'query {PriceQuery(basevehicleidnumber :"'+value.worldpacinfo.basevehicleidnumber+'",parttypeidnumber:"'+value.worldpacinfo.parttypeidnumber+'",productpartnumber:"'+value.worldpacinfo.productpartnumber+'"){corefee,retailprice}}',
                    }).then(resp1 => {
                        value.worldpacinfo['retailprice']=resp1.data.data.PriceQuery.retailprice;
                        value.worldpacinfo['corefee']=resp1.data.data.PriceQuery.corefee;
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
            })
        }
        //console.log(productsArr);
        this.product = productsArr;
        this.emit("change");
    }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I have called this method in store on componentWillMount

Comment: Where is your flux store,action？

Comment: @AndrewCarl The above code i have pasted is the code of store, and i have called this method into componentWillMount method. I have called an API inside another API because Nested calls depended on the outer API call, But when First API call is complete it not waiting to finish the inner api calls, it is directly jumping to 'this.emit("change")' statement and rendering the component. I am not able to access the ' value.worldpacinfo["retailprice"]' these field. For now i have used Sync nested calls but it is too slow to load the page, can you please give me any solution?